# Attach Metadata to Class Object

Tags: apex, custom-field

I am looking for a way to attach metadata to an Apex Class.  My scenario is as follows:

Suppose you have 40 custom Apex classes.  There are two major systems that use these classes, but system A uses only the first 20 and system B uses only the second 20.

I want to be able to query on the Apex class collection with a filter that lets me get only relevant results.

```
Select * from Class where Type = "A"
```

- Does not return B specific classes.
- Does not return standard classes.
- Does not return other custom classes.

Is this possible ? 
I know an alternative option is to use something of a namespace in the name to define what type each class is.  Then I can do a `LIKE` query to get classes with that prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this, no.  Besides adding a fake namespace, which is probably the most straightforward, I suppose you could create a custom object or custom setting to store the list of classes and any other metadata you want.  Then you can query that in your code.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.  I think you're probably correct but I wanted verification.  I actually thought of this solution with the object to carry references to the classes as well.  I will most likely use fake namespaces in my solution.